# Is 160 the maximum carry weight with saddlebags?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am level 16. Can my current carry weight of 160 get any higher? Is this the max or will I be able to get better saddlebags later in the game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on posts in threads like [this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/71881689), it seems like 160 is the maximum carry weight possible in the base game.

> User 1: Mines 90, wondering if it can be higher?
>
> User 2: 160
>
> User 3: Mine's 130lbs. I think you can go up to 160lbs tho

However, if you have Blood and Wine, you're able to get a 110 carry weight saddlebag (full list of saddlebags can be seen [here](http://thewitcher3.wiki.fextralife.com/Saddlebags)), which brings your maximum to 230, or 250 with the Fiend Decoction, as mentioned [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/74174144):

> 230 is max carry weight (with the 110 saddle bags (B&W) + 60 carry weight skill)
>
> Actually the max Is 250, the Fiend Decoction Increases the limit by 20.

Comment: The inventory capacity can be increased to 180 using Fiend Decoction, however it has very high toxicity